# How adding the appropriate Except to a program when reading from a file in python?

Tags: python, exception

I have been trying to capture an exception that returns the message "Error in file!" when reading from a file in Python.

I had managed to catch the error when the file isn't existing, but unfortunately I couldn't manage to capture the error when there is an error in a file.
Any suggestions?

```
try:
   # ...
except IOError:
   print("Error opening file!")
except Exception:
   print("Error in file!")  
   raise
```

Comment: What file type are you reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the exception to find out what exactly went wrong in the try-block, so you can handle the new error.

In order to do this, just print details of the exception:

```
try:
    ....
except Exception as f:
    print(f.__class__)
    print(str(f))
```

This will give you the class of the error (e.g. NameError) and the specific error the program encountered. So, you can handle it with an additional except-clause or debug the code.